# Teste unitário (JUnit e Mockito) - Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

Estou escrevendo o teste de um método findByID():

```
public DoctorDTO getDoctorById(long id) throws DoctorNotFoundException {
        Optional<Doctor> doctorO = VerifyIfExists(id);

        return doctorMapper.toDTO(doctorO.get());
}

private Optional<Doctor> VerifyIfExists(long id) throws DoctorNotFoundException {
        Optional<Doctor> doctorO = doctorRepository.findById(id);
        if (doctorO.isEmpty()) {
            throw new DoctorNotFoundException(id);
        }
        return doctorO;
}
```

Como podem ver, eu uso um Mapper para retornar um tipo DoctorDTO.

No meu teste, usando o mockito:

```
@Mock
DoctorRepository doctorRepository;

@Mock
DoctorMapper doctorMapper;

@InjectMocks
DoctorService doctorService;

@Test
void testGivenValidDoctorThenReturnThisDoctor() throws DoctorNotFoundException {

        DoctorDTO expectedDoctorDTO = createFakeDoctorDTO();
        Doctor expectedDoctor =  createFakeEntity();

        when(doctorRepository.findById(expectedDoctor.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(expectedDoctor));
        when(doctorMapper.toDTO(expectedDoctor)).thenReturn(expectedDoctorDTO);

        DoctorDTO doctorDTO = doctorService.getDoctorById(expectedDoctor.getId());

        assertEquals(expectedDoctorDTO, doctorDTO);

        assertEquals(expectedDoctorDTO.getCrm(), doctorDTO.getCrm());
        assertEquals(expectedDoctorDTO.getName(), doctorDTO.getName());

    }
```

Me é retornado que **when(doctorMapper.toDTO(expectedDoctor)).thenReturn(expectedDoctorDTO);**

não é utilizado, porém o meu método (doctorService.getDoctorByID) utiliza doctorMapper.toDTO. Alguém saberia dizer por que a mensagem seguinte aparece quando rodo o teste ?

```
Unnecessary stubbings detected. Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code. Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code): 1. -> at com.example.medicalrecordapi.services.DoctorServiceTest.testGivenValidDoctorThenReturnThisDoctor(DoctorServiceTest.java:61) Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.
```

Estou usando o Mockito de forma errada?

Answer (score 1):

Debugando o teste, eu notei que estava sendo criada dois MOCKS de MAPPER pelo Mockito, fazendo com que esse `when(doctorMapper.toDTO(expectedDoctor)).thenReturn(expectedDoctorDTO);`

nunca fosse executado, pois referenciava um Mock diferente do que deveria.

Eu corrigi mudando lá na minha classe Mapper o modo como ele seria injetado na classe Service.

Antes o Mapper estava assim:

```
@Mapper
public interface DoctorMapper {

    DoctorMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(DoctorMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "birthDate", source = "birthDate", dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy")

    Doctor toModel(DoctorDTO doctorDTO);

    DoctorDTO toDTO(Doctor doctor);
}
```

Lá no service eu injetava a dependência assim:

```
private final DoctorMapper doctorMapper = DoctorMapper.INSTANCE;
```

Eu retirei o INSTANCE do Mapper e passei a injetar através do construtor @AllArgsConstructor do Lombok. Ele basicamente injeta pra você as dependências e te poupa de escrever os construtores.

Depois disso o Mock foi feito de forma correta e o teste passou como esperado.

O Mapper ficou assim:

```
@Mapper
public interface DoctorMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "birthDate", source = "birthDate", dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy")

    Doctor toModel(DoctorDTO doctorDTO);

    DoctorDTO toDTO(Doctor doctor);
}
```

E injetei a dependência assim:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class DoctorService {

    private final DoctorMapper doctorMapper;

    private final DoctorRepository doctorRepository;

...
```